# PowerBI PBIX files in Azure Cloud workspaces automatic update efficiency

Tags: node.js, azure, powerbi-embedded

I have build a script in Node.js to automatically refresh all workspaces in the Azure cloud with locally saved PBIX files.

Currently PBIX files are refreshed each hour on my local server to maintain up-to-date reports. Once refreshed the PBIX files must be uploaded to the Azure cloud.

Every time a PBIX file is refreshed, the workspace in Azure cloud linked to this PBIX file must be updated. I upload the PBIX files with the Azure REST API.

Unfortunately, the Azure REST API does not support updating/deleting a single workspace. Therefore I query to delete the entire workspace collection and afterwards add each PBIX file back to the Azure cloud.

The method does work, yet it is somewhat inconvenient. Each PBIX file is around 30 megabytes large, also the data to upload hourly is getting huge.

I am looking into DirectQuery or any other streaming process to just stream raw database data to the Azure workspaces, unfortunately without success.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understand regarding your question, updating pbix reports into workspace would be delete and replace with new one every time, as of now power BI supports only this feature, updating existing one may not possible.